# Incorrect storage calculation on OSX Yosemite

Tags: storage, osx-yosemite

Several days ago my storage started getting full. When I check the Storage tab I get the following picture:

[image]

My guess is that apps shouldn't be more than around 10GB here, I have no idea where the remaining is coming from.

Can anyone please tell how to find how much free storage do I actually have?

Comment: What makes you think your guess is more accurate than what the OS reports?

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton, 120.12 - 53.65 = 66.47 GB while only apps take more than 88.96 GB :))

Comment: You have 53.65GB  OS X report disk sizes in base 10 not base 2

Answer (score 2):

You can view your actual free storage on any drive by selecting your hard drive in the Finder and press <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd> to get information on it.

The error probably occurs because the size calculated in the `About This Mac` window is done from file metadata information that is collected into the Spotlight index. To fix this you can rebuild the Spotlight index as described in [a support article from Apple](http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht2409)